# Fresh Install of 2.0, Nothing is showing, menu or products

Tags: magento2

So i don't understand what is going on.  I have added categories, product and added widgets to the home page.  But nothing is showing up.

No Menu,
No Products,
No Categories,
No Widgets

Currently have a single store setup, (tried both with no avail), everything is active and enabled. The categories are setup as anchor. Flushed cache. Reloaded page. Flushed local cache. It really shouldn't be this hard to figure out.

I don't know what else to do in order to make this work.

Any ideas?

Thanks
-C

Comment: Have you clean cache by command line ?

Comment: Yes, about 4 or 5 times unfortunately

Comment: Have you re-indexing ?

Comment: Yes, a few times

Comment: using SSH, btw for clairification

Comment: Make sure your categories are subcategories of the root category (Default Category). Check that your products are active and are in stock.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below things:

1. Check folders permissions.
2. Check your categories are enabled or not.
3. Check weather you assigned products to categories or not.
4. Make sure products are active and in stock.
5. Check products and categories url redirect are created or not.If not then you need to run full indexing for this.

hope this will help thanks.